# Astroposition function in wolfra cloud

Tags: astronomy

I am trying to copy paste and compute the input given in this link for the movement of mars.
But wolfram cloud gives error.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AstroGraphics.html

When compute below instruction

```
mars = AstroPosition[Entity["Planet", "Mars"], {"Equatorial", #}] & /@
    DateRange["1 Jul 2022", "1 July 2023", "Week"];
```

I get the error shown below

```
"15/07/2022 12:00 am is not a valid location specification"
```

and similarly for some more dates.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: That's a curious way things to fail. Try wrapping date strings in `DateObject` functions, like `AstroPosition[Entity["Planet", "Mars"], {"Equatorial", #}] & /@ DateRange[DateObject["1 Jul 2022"], DateObject["1 July 2023"], "Week"]`

Comment: You might be interested to try to evaluate `Here` on the same session. It should return an estimate of your geographic position as `GeoPosition`. Maybe it hasn't been resolved for you? Cloud version works for me, but it also has a value for `Here`.

Comment: @kirma thanks it worked. Guess I have to wrap in DateObJect.                                  
 "Here" command gets evaluated to my lat long. So it does get resolved.

Comment: I'm still not quite certain why that fixed it, but using string-form dates on `DateRange` makes it also emit strings instead of `DateObjects` (which is frankly, in my opinion, strange), and something in the machinery didn't like that...